# Java 8 Refining Lambda Map<String, List<String>> to String With Map Key Requirement

Tags: java, java-8

The keys of the map may be values 1 - 5 where each key is not required, but if absent must concatenate something that looks like " - [] ".

I've used Java 8 a bit before and I feel like this can be done more efficiently with stream() and collect() but I feel like the external list requirement is throwing me off.  The below code works but feels incorrect.

```
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");

StringBuilder location = new StringBuilder();

ids.forEach(id -> {
    List<String> addresses = map.get(id);
    if (addresses != null) {
        addresses.forEach(addr -> location.append(addr + " - "));
    } else {
        location.append(" [] - ");
    }
});
```

Generates something that looks like this for a Colorado location:

```
US - CO - [] - CENTENNIAL -
```

In answer to Nicholas K an example of map would be

```
{1=[US], 2=[CO], 5=[METROPOLITAN FOOTBALL STADIUM DISTRICT, REGIONAL TRANSPORTATION DISTRICT]}
```

and would be expected to receive output

```
US - CO - [] - [] - METROPOLITAN FOOTBALL STADIUM DISTRICT - REGIONAL TRANSPORTATION DISTRICT
```

Comment: What are the values for `map`?

Comment: Don't assume that `stream()` and `collect()` will be more efficient, write the code in the way you're most comfortable with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to handle missing values in a map is [`computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) which is a new method on `Map` available since Java 8.

This gives you the below code:

```
String s = ids.stream()
    .map(id -> map.computeIfAbsent(id, absentKey -> singletonList("[]")))
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" - "));
```

- First, let's stream over the keys in the map, which you have stored in the `ids` list variable.
- Then, if the value is null, map to a default value (`"[]"`), else `computeIfAbsent()` returns the actual value.
- Since you want to print all the values separated by `" - "`, let's just flat map the stream of lists and join them by `" - "`.

`s` now holds the value (if used with your example map):

```
"US - CO - [] - [] - METROPOLITAN FOOTBALL STADIUM DISTRICT - REGIONAL TRANSPORTATION DISTRICT"
```

Notice that there is no trailing `" - "`. `Collectors.joining()` makes sure to not append the delimiter before or after the elements.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `Stream` and `Optional` to handle `null` references:

```
List<String> result = ids.stream()
  .map(index -> format(map.get(index)))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(result);
```

And the method `format`:

```
  private static String format(List<String> address) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(address)
      .map(a -> a.stream().map(part -> Optional.ofNullable(part).orElse("[]")).collect(Collectors.joining(" - ")))
      .orElse(" [] - ");
  }
```

Applied on an example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = Map.of("1", Arrays.asList("US", "CO", null, "CENTENNIAL"));

    List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");

    List<String> result = ids.stream()
      .map(index -> format(map.get(index)))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);
  }
```

That prints:

```
[US - CO - [] - CENTENNIAL,  [] - ,  [] - ,  [] - ,  [] - ]
```

Comment: Looks promising, I've not used Optional before I'll look into this, thanks.

Comment: Suggestion - If you've used `Map.of`, you can also use `List.of`. Of course considering them to be unmodifiable.

Comment: @nullpointer Generally you're right. And I started with `List.of(...)` but to show the handling of `null` I switched to `Arrays.asList(...)` since `List.of()` "Throws: `NullPointerException` - if an element is `null`" ([JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E,E)))

Comment: @LuCio oh yeah, correct, you're initializing the list within the Map as well and with `null` and that reveals the picture so clear as to why the `List.of` throws an NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler approach :

```
    ids.stream().map(l -> map.get(Integer.parseInt(l))).forEach(i -> {
        if (i != null) {
            location.append(i + " - ");
        } else {
            location.append("[] - ");
        }
    });
```

Here we loop over each element in the list to see whether it is present as a key in the map. Depending on the value we append the appropriate *strings*.

Note:

Parsing has been done assuming your map is defined as `Map<Integer, String>`

Comment: `List<String> addresses = map.get(id);` from the question. The assumption is incorrect.

Comment: What @nullpointer says is correct so I wouldn't have to do the Integre.parseInt.  Is there a way to lose the StringBuilder and collect to Strings at the end.  I know about Collectors.joining but can I do that inside the if-else?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not very clean, but you can try :

```
Map<String, List<String>> inputMap = Map.of("1", List.of(), "2", List.of("l1", "l2"));
List<String> ids = List.of("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
StringBuilder location = new StringBuilder();
ids.forEach(id -> {
    if (inputMap.get(id) != null) {
        location.append(inputMap.get(id).stream().map(addr -> addr + " - ").collect(Collectors.joining()));
    } else {
        location.append(" [] - ");
    }
});
```